# cast, join and reduce data with reshape

Tags: r, reshape

I've got a dataframe that looks like

```
MAP  name       series    ID
1.0  aspartame  baseline  902349
1.0  aspartame  baseline  82749
1.0  aspartame  baseline  928542
1.0  aspartame  next      928542
0.8  aspartame  next      82749
0.8  aspartame  next      902349
```

And I'd like to join this data on ID and calculate the difference
between baseline and next in the MAP score. so this should give

```
diff name       ID
0.2  aspartame  902349
0.2  aspartame  82749
0.0  aspartame  928542
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by OP: A solution using `reshape` (or rather `reshape2`).

```
d <- read.table(text = "
MAP  name       series    ID
1.0  aspartame  baseline  902349
1.0  aspartame  baseline  82749
1.0  aspartame  baseline  928542
1.0  aspartame  next      928542
0.8  aspartame  next      82749
0.8  aspartame  next      902349", header = TRUE)

require(reshape2)

dcast(data = d, formula = ID  + name~ ., value.var = "MAP", 
      fun.aggregate = function(x) (x[1] - x[2]))
```

gives

```
      ID      name  NA
1  82749 aspartame 0.2
2 902349 aspartame 0.2
3 928542 aspartame 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way in base R (assuming your `data.frame` is named `df`):

```
aggregate(list(MAP = df$MAP), 
          by=list(ID = df$ID, name = df$name), 
          function(x) x[1] - x[2])
#       ID      name MAP
# 1  82749 aspartame 0.2
# 2 902349 aspartame 0.2
# 3 928542 aspartame 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use plyr:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(your_data, c("ID", "name"), 
      function(df){subset(df, series == "baseline", select = "MAP")-  
        subset(df, series == "next", select = "MAP")})
```